# Android: Check whether String value equals [""]

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

Sorry to ask this, but I am confused how to check whether a String value is equal to `[""]`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean [""] or ""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For double quote contained in your string you should always **escape it** as `\"` for each occurrence of double quote.

hence you would compare as follows:

```
myStr.equals("[\"\"]")
```

If you are talking about just checking if the string is empty you simply do the following

```
myStr.equals("")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(s.equals("[\"\"]")) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Java tutorial for characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), any string that contains a `"` character will need to escape these using `\"`

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler

You can then escape the special character in the string and test if you string is equal using the following: `myString.equals("[\"\"]")`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers,  Android provides an excellent API called **TextUtils** to perform check operations on Strings (or CharSequence).

So if your question was to check if your String is empty (`""`) you may use `TextUtils.isEmpty(myStr)` witch will return true if the String is either Null or empty.

It's similar to C# `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

More details here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty